# Using where clause to find descendants - Rails 3.0 and Ancestry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, parent-child

How can I find records in a table that are descendants of another record using the where clause (to only get those records from the database)?

Let's say I have a tree with locations. The root locations are countries, the locations at the next level are states, and their children nodes are cities. How can I, using the where clause, find only cities in a certain state?

I planned on checking if the cities' ancestry strings included the state's ancestry string, but I couldn't figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the scopes generated by [Ancestry](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry), for example `children_of(node)` where you can give the id of the state.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a table called 'locations', you could create 3 different models all using this locations table:

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name 'locations'
  has_many :states, :class_name => 'State', foreign_key => "parent_id"
end

class State < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name 'locations'
  has_many :cities, :class_name => 'City', foreign_key => "parent_id"
  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => "Country"
end

class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name 'locations'
  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => "State"
end
```

Now you can use something like

```
countries = Country.find(:all, :conditions => {:parent_id => nil } )
```

as countries are the 'root elements', so they do not have a parent.
For each country you can find the states on a similar way, say 'usa' has id 1 its states can be found by:

```
states = State.find(:all, :conditions => {:parent_id => 1 } )
```

or if you already put usa in a variable by just this

```
usa.states
```

See the [Rails Association guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) for more info on the `:class_name`, `:foreign_key` and other `has_many` options used in the example.

*Note*: Hope I did not made (too much) mistakes, but I did something similar to this with menus, sub-menus and their items.

*Note2*: Of course it would be much simpler if you use 3 tables for the countries, states and cities. Then you can use just straightforward associations.